# Word or term for the containment and shelving properties of an object? (might be science question)

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

### Backstory

A roommate left their car key on the microwave. I typed her an email about leaving her key on the microwave. Google spell check suggested that "on the" should be "in the" microwave.

I found myself wanting to refer to the property of all vessels to contain other items, as well as, the property of objects to support other objects.

For example, a book case is better at shelving than an orange is. A book case has an outstanding "shelving property?"

Or another example, spell check seemed to suggest that if an item possesses the *containment property* it must lack the *shelving property*.

### Question:

Are there specific words which describe these object properties?

Perhaps this should be in the Physics Stack Exchange?

Surely someone has needed to measure, compare or describe a vessels containment ability before and needed to refer to it?

Comment: _Dimensionality_ will do, same as it does in math. Metaphors can refer to 0-, 1-, 2-, or 3-dimensional locations, with objects and prepositions to match. Natural language doesn't go beyond 3-space, and doesn't require real numbers.  It matches a model of human motion in 2½ dimensions in a 1-G field.

Comment: As long as we get **in** a car and **on** a train — no. There's no consistent containment v. support logic in the language.

Comment: It would be too easy to simply ignore the Spellcheck suggestion?

Comment: I have a bookcase with a glass door that has both the "containment" and "shelving" properties.

Comment: How humans like to arrange items seems more like an anthropological question than a physics question. Unless you'd like to discuss the permeability or hermeticity or robustness of an enclosure?

Comment: An enclosed bookcase contains as well as offering shelving. A tin of chocolates is said to contain chocolates whether the lid is on or off. A plate of scones is not said to contain scones. But the 3-D ... 2-D analysis contains many examples where judgement calls have to be made (and were in the past, conferring idiomaticity of various on- or in-phrases. Metaphors have become fixed – idioms. 'On the train' is used for when one is a passenger, but 'There was a bat in the train!'

Answer (score 0):

I think that you question is not well formed. How well a bookcase is at shelving books is not dependent only on the bookcase itself, but on the items being shelved. I have a bookcase that contains many of my books but some of my books are too large for it, and some of them are small, meaning that the space is not used efficiently.

Similarly, it may be good at shelving books but if I want to store gold bars on there (if only I had some :-)) they may well fit, but they are so heavy that the shelf may break.

And of course, if I want to store elephants on my shelf then it is both insufficiently voluminous and insufficiently strong.

So, in a sense I think "interior volume" may be the answer, but the problem is that it isn't really a property only of the book case but of the items to be shelved. In a sense it is more a functional property -- its value depending on both the subject and the object -- rather than an static, intrinsic property of the item itself.

But as you say, that isn't a language question, it is for a different domain.

Comment: Yes, the OP seems to think that being able to put X on Y is equivalent to saying Y is a shelf or is good as a shelf. In practice, there are many ways you can put X on Y, and many senses of "on", not all of which involve laying an object with a flat base on a flat platform.

Comment: Good points. It is a relationship in both instances and not a property.