# Is there a word that means "fittable" as in an object's capability to fit into a space?

Tags: single-word-requests

A friend used the word "fittable" in conversation a few days ago when discussing whether or not some objects could fit into a box. It led to a discussion about whether or not "fittable" is a word (according to Google it is, but it is obsolete), and whether or not there is a better word to describe what he was trying to say. We weren't able to come up with any alternatives, but it felt like we must have been missing something obvious. Is there a word that means an item's capability to fit within a space?

Comment: It won't suit all contexts, but ***stowable*** would sometimes work. I wouldn't like to accept ***fittable*** myself (I'd say ***That fits / will fit***, not ***That's fittable***), but others may think different.

Comment: Forget the adjective and say the object fits in the box.

Comment: 'Placeable' has the sense 'capable of being placed' and 'locatable', 'capable of being 'located'. These words are current, but the subsense you require (physical insertion of an object) seems quite a stretch.

Comment: ...sounds a little like Tetris.

Comment: There isn't a word because this isn't how we normally think about the world. The attribute pertains to the container, not the item inside. We ask whether the box is big enough, not whether the item is small enough. There are a few special exceptions, like standard pallets, ISO containers, and rail cars, where you are kind of stuck with the standardized transport system and have to design and build to that specification. "Palletizable" and "containerable" are both understood in this context.

Comment: For a to fit inside b, a must be smaller than b. That is the only pre-requisite. Whatever its size, if a is _smaller_ than b then a can be **accommodated** in b . It is a passive concept since a is the focus and b is the locative aspect. The question focuses (wrongly I would say) on the 'ability of a to be accommodated' rather than the ability of b to have the _capacity_ to accommodate. That is the problem with the wording, I would suggest.

Comment: **Packable** is used in math and engineering in the general sense of "fitting inside."

Comment: @DjinTonic — Not to mention suitcases.

Comment: @DjinTonic I was going to say same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems or https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2740:_Square_Packing

Comment: This question is more abstract but related: [Word or term for the containment and shelving properties of an object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568621/word-or-term-for-the-containment-and-shelving-properties-of-an-object-might-be)

Comment: _Fittable_ is not obsolete but it is rare, though I've never heard it. _OED_ is kind of mocking the word with this definition: "_rare._  Apparently only attested in dictionaries or glossaries. That may be fitted." Also, the first sense in [_Wiktionary_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fittable) (the sense you want) is not obsolete: "Capable of being fitted." Thus, if you really want to use it, use it; but there are common ways to say it of course. When I've searched "is fittable" in Google, I found some examples in different contexts like programming, mechanics, patents.

Comment: @ermanen: I suspect you're looking at usages related to the (to me, perfectly ordinary) term [***retrofittable***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22retrofittable%22) - deriving from the dense of ***to fit*** = ***to install*** (where you might have a *retrofittable* feature added to your car because it wasn't automatically included in the model you bought).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, _fittable_ and _retrofittable_ have different meanings, and _fittable_ is rare unlike _retrofittable_. I wouldn't be surprised if people have misused the word in some mechanical context but I've found examples where they have genuinely chosen to use "fittable" meaning "capable of being fitted".

Comment: @ermanen: Yes, that's what I meant. We wouldn't normally refer to an optional car feature as ***fittable*** ( = *capable of being installed*), because it *must* have that attribute in order to exist in the first place. But ***retrofittable*** is meaningful, because it adds the specific information that the feature can be fitted after the vehicle leaves the factory. But even though the "unqualified" version is far less common than the ***retro-*** version, I'd still expect most written instances of ***fittable*** to mean "able to be installed", not "able to fit in the available space".

Comment: @StuartF Therefore the word must be **containable**.  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40042?redirectedFrom=containable#eid) _a1691   R. Boyle Wks. (1772) I. 85 (R.)   The air **containable** within the cavity of the æolipile, amounted to eleven grains_

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion:

[***insertability***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insertable)

> Able to be inserted; able to be put into something else.

See also: [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insertable)

Your post is a little unclear whether you are talking about packing a single object into a slightly larger object, or if this is some sort of packaging scheme  for multiple objects of the same size or different shapes.

That would make this an Analytical Geometry issue...possibly "derivative drivel", to quote a source.

Answer (score 3):

> We weren't able to come up with any alternatives,

I suspect this is because the word does not exist. There are already simple, standard, and efficient ways of expressing the idea:

"Will it/they fit/go in here?"

"Is it too small/big for there?"

> but it felt like we must have been missing something obvious.

That is caused by a myth that circulates: "English has a word for everything." ... it does not.

Comment: Maybe not, but I've heard Chinese does.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a word that means an item's capability to fit within a space?**

---

a1691   R. Boyle Wks. (1772) I. 85 (R.)   The air **containable** within the cavity of the æolipile, amounted to eleven grains.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40042?redirectedFrom=containable#eid)

Thus the word would be 'containability' and that word is available in the English language and may be used by anyone who wishes to use it.

As yet, nobody has had a use for it, but now, after the question has been posed, there would appear to be a need for it.